# Setting HTML elements in one line? (inputs, p)

Tags: html, css, alignment

So I'm working on this page and no matter what I do with the CSS, I can't get the text aligned in a single line. (yes I have tried `overflow:hidden;` and `white-space:nowrap;`

Here is the code in which I want aligned:

```
<div class="dates">
<p>From</p> 
<input id="dateFrom"></div>
<p>To</p>
<input id="dateTo"></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking for help with?

Comment: @RohitVerma He doesn't need bootstrap

Comment: nope rohit verma

Comment: `p` tags are default `display: block;`. have you changed the display value at all? like `display: inline;`

Comment: @NuclearApe yes, changed it now

Comment: @zgood Changing the default `display` of an element is not a good pattern to get into. Instead, use the appropriate element for the job.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree actually, its also important to unstand what the css `display` property does and what default values are.

Comment: Whoever downvoted all the answers below, perhaps you should take a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down - downvotes are for an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.  The below is none of that and actually solves the problem, just because you don't agree with the semantics does not mean they're wrong.  Stop being so quick to downvote and spoil this site

Comment: @HereticMonkey there is nothing wrong with changing the `display` of an element - as long as the html is semantically correct then it doesn't matter what the display is - after all in the code where you use a label, if I wanted to give that label a width, I would make it inline block - nothing wrong with that at all

Comment: @Pete That is certainly an opinion, as is your opinion about when to downvote. 
My opinion differs. The tooltip on the downvote button is simple: "This answer is not useful". See also [this answer on Should I downvote an answer only on its quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310627).

Comment: @Pete... The highest voted answer says not to vote on an answer based on the question. Note sure how that bolsters your point. Downvotes are not "hatred" and people who insist on declaring it thus are part of the problem. Voting is an assessment of the usefulness of the answer, nothing else (certainly not the answerer). But go ahead and bring in an imaginary us-vs-them mentality to an otherwise objective quality measure, by all means.

Comment: @Pete Regarding design questions, I said it is not a good pattern to get into, not that it isn't occasionally necessary. The first instinct should be to use the most semantically correct element, not hack the default CSS of an inappropriate element, which is what many of the post's answers (and zgood's initial comment) were suggesting.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's not imaginary - https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ also at the end of the downvoting page link: *The up-vote privilege comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top. Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the appropriate markup for the content you have. Your control labels are not paragraphs. Use label elements.

```html
<div class="dates">
  <label for=dateFrom>From</label>
  <input id="dateFrom"></div>
<div class="dates">
  <label for=dateTo>To</label>
  <input id="dateTo">
</div>
```

Comment: just to add... using the appropriate markup is better for things like screen readers and web crawlers

Answer (score 0):

add the following css

```
p, input {
display: inline-block;
}
```